# how to create alternate blocks in bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I basically have a row with 3 sets of columns and I want the following layout (using bootstrap 5), basically Image on the left, text on the right. Next columns have text on the left, image on the right and finally image on the left, text on the right again

```
Image  Text
Text   Image
Image  Text
```

I tried something like the below but it messes things up on mobile. On mobile it should always be the image first and then the text.

```
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">Some text</div>

<div class="col-md-6 order-last"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">Some text</div>

<div class="col-md-6 order-last"><img src="..." /></div>
<div class="col-md-6" class="order-last">Some text</div>
```

Comment: are the layout elements being generated dynamically ? If that's the case, which programming language are you using ?

Comment: No, not dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
      <div class="main-container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
          <p>Some dummy text </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row-reverse">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
          <p>Some dummy text </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
          <p>Some dummy text </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for this. It does work to an extent but the responsiveness isn't great because it isn't using bootstrap columns I suppose. Is there not another way using `col-md`, `col-lg` etc?

Comment: Try it .. it works perfectly due to changing between flex-column and flex-md-row. This handles responsivness in different screens.

However, you can add col-md-6 to image-container and text-container if you want